# $ |f(z)-p_n(z)|\le (n+2)|z|^{n+1} $ with $ \deg(p_n(z))\le n $ over the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $ f(z) $ be a holomorphic function over the unit disk $ \Delta:=\{ z\in \mathbb C: |z|<1 \} $. Suppose that $ |f(z)|\le 1 $ for $ z\in\Delta $. Show that for any positive integer $ n $, there is a polynomial $ p_n(z) $ of degree at most $ n $ such that $$ |f(z)-p_n(z)|\le (n+2)|z|^{n+1} $$
>   for any $ z\in \Delta $.

---

My attempt:

I notice that if we take $ p_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}z^k $, then 
\begin{align}
\left|f(z)-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}z^k\right|&=\left| \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}z^k \right|\\
&\le\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty |z|^k\\
&\le\frac{|z|^{n+1}}{1-|z|}
\end{align}
If $ |z|\le\frac{n+1}{n+2} $, we have proved $ |f(z)-p_n(z)|\le (n+2)|z|^{n+1} $, but what about $ \frac{n+1}{n+2}<|z|<1 $ ?

Comment: How did you get rid of $f^{k}(0)/k!$ in the first inequality (from first to second displayed line)?

Comment: @uniquesolution By Cauchy inequalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it is like this: let $f(z)=\sum{a_kz^k}, p_n(z)=\sum_{0\le k \le n}a_kz^k$; note that $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}{|f(re^{i\theta})|^2}d{\theta}=\sum{|a_k|^2r^{2k}},\ 0<r<1, $$ so $|f(z)| \le 1$ implies trivially $ |a_k|^2r^{2k}\le 1, 0<r<1 $, so taking $r \to 1$ we get $|a_k| \le 1$ for all $ k $.

Let $$g(z)=\frac{f(z)-p_n(z)}{z^{n+1}},$$  $g$ analytic in the unit disc; fix $0<r<1$, hence by maximum modulus for $|z|\le r,$ \begin{align} |g(z)| &\le \sup_{|w|=r}{\frac{|f(w)-p_n(w)|}{r^{n+1}}} \\
&\le \sup_{|w|=r}{\frac{|f(w)|+|p_n(w)|}{r^{n+1}}}\\
& \le \frac{1+\sum_{0\le k \le n}|a_k|}{r^{n+1}} \\
&\le \frac{n+2}{r^{n+1}}.\end{align} Letting $r \to 1$ we get $|g(z)| \le n+2$ in the whole (open) unit disc and we are done!

Comment: Nice! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome